# Building a Binary Search Tree from a sorted array of struct pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Im trying to print a build a BST from a sorted array of struct pointers. The program seems to have segmentation fault after calling the *make_tree()* function.
Is there something I'm skipping in the make_tree(). Any suggestions are helpful.

> My struct

```
typedef struct student{
  char *name;  /* student name */
  char *number; /* student number */
  struct student *left; /* pointer to left subtree */
  struct student *right; /* pointer to right subtree */

}Student;
```

> main.c

```
tree = make_tree (tree, array_of_students, 0, CLASS_SIZE-1);
printf("\nIn Order traversal:\n");
print_inorder(tree);
```

> function

```
Student* make_tree(Student *tree, Student *arr[], int left, int right)
{
    if (left > right)
        return NULL;
    int mid = (left + right) / 2;
    Student *tree1 = (Student*) malloc(30* sizeof(Student));

    tree1->left = make_tree(tree, arr, left, mid - 1);
    tree1->right = make_tree(tree, arr, mid + 1, right);

    return tree1;
}
void print_inorder(Student *node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    print_inorder(node->left);
    print_inorder(node->right);
    printf("%s\n", node->name);
}
```

Comment: What are the arguments `tree` and `arr` for?

Comment: @MikeCAT The `arr` is the sorted array that contains data

Comment: If all you want to do is create a tree from a sorted sequence, the `tree` argument to `make_tree` serves no purpose. For that matter, you don't need a left and right argument either; you can just use an array base, a length, and pointer arithmetic to recurse the right side of the current segment during the build.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `printf("%s\n", node->name);` in the `print_inorder()` function, but the `name` member is not initialized. Initialize it properly (maybe in the `make_tree()` function).

Also note that casting results of `malloc()` is considered as a bad practice.